# Browser back goes two JSF pages back

Tags: jsf-2

I have a JSF page with a form.  The submit button is an `<h:commantButton>` with an action that calls a backing bean function, which in turn does some calculations and then returns a string which is the name of the next page to view.

This works as expected.  On this page is an `<h:link>` with an outcome of another JSF page.  When on this third page if the user clicks the browser back button they are taken to the first page with the form and not the second page.  Why is this?  I should mention that the backing bean is session scoped.

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal, if you verify your URL, you will see that it doesn't change when you click on the `h:commandButton`. If you want it to change correctly in the first place, you can modify your action like this : `youraction?faces-redirect=true`.

**More info :**

[JSF : Page Forward vs Page Redirect](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-page-forward-vs-page-redirect/)